# jQuery Validate - how to remove error class onkeyup after submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validate plugin.

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent('.form-group').addClass('error-sign-up');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent('.form-group').removeClass('error-sign-up');
    },
    onfocusout:false,
    onkeyup:false,
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
        },
    },
    messages: {

        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
        }
    }
})
```

After the submit I want to remover the error onkeyup on the element.
Now the errors are removed only if the user click submit again.

I use

```
onfocusout:false
    onkeyup:false
```

for not execute the validation onfocusout/onkeyup

Comment: You can reset the form after submit like

$("#loginForm").resetForm();

Comment: If you want the error class to be removed by the `onkeyup` trigger, then why are you disabling it?  Remove `onkeyup: false` and then the error will be removed as intended.

Comment: You are causing the condition you're complaining about.  If you don't want validation triggered on `keyup` or `focusout`, then clicking the submit a second time is the only trigger remaining.

Comment: @Sparky- you right. I confused

Answer (score 0):

```
onfocusout:false
onkeyup:false
```

You are causing the condition you're complaining about. If you disable the `onkeyup` and `onfocusout` triggers by setting them to `false`, then clicking the submit button is the only validation trigger that remains.

If you want the error class to be removed by the `onkeyup` or `onfocusout` trigger, then do not disable them. Remove `onkeyup: false` and  `onfocusout: false` and then the errors will be removed as intended by the default settings.

Comment: @Sparky- you are right regarding the onkeyup, but not regarding the onfocusout. I can leave it true

Comment: @SaritRotshild, I think you're confused... what do you mean *"leave it true"*.  You absolutely cannot set `onfocusout` to `true` as this will break the plugin.  You need to read the docs:  ["A boolean `true` is **not** a valid value."](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout).  As per my answer, I said, "remove" the `onfocusout` option to use the default behavior, and never set it to `true`.

Comment: @Sparky- I read, and I can. I don't want that the validation will execute on focusout, only on submit

Comment: @SaritRotshild, ok, but this is answering your original question!

Comment: @Sparky- As I said I just needed to remove the onkeyup

Comment: @SaritRotshild, that's fine... however, that does not make my answer incorrect.  All information contained above is factually accurate... simply use the information as you see fit.